# software for meeting

Tags: video-conferencing, user-management, meetings

I'm looking for software that allow me to create video live meeting, with management user system.
I want that every user will enter with user name and password from one device only (i would like to block duplicate connections), also I want ability to see the participants but they can see and hear only me.

**edit**

The goal is to broadcast fitness training for registered training only, I have looked at webinars but the main concern is that people will send the invitation to the webinar to people who are not registered, so I need the ability to block it.
Therefore, no sharing desktop is required, the operating system is windows, the initial number of participants is up to 100 but if everything goes well the number will increase
I would appreciate any information.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! What OS should that software run on? Any price considerations? How many simultaneous users must be supported? What other features do you need (e.g. desktop sharing)? Some pointers on the use case (what are you trying to achieve, like teaching classes and how an "average session" would run) might also help for well-matched recommendations. Thanks!